# Column A value fills in Column B value

Tags: list, 2013, custom-list

I have a separate list with information that I would like to fill another list but I am unsure how to do this or where to learn how to do this.  I have list `echo` that has a column A titled `Name` and column B is titled `client` with other columns that have information such as contact details.   However, in list `bravo` I would like to fill in a column with `client` and the `Name` from the other list will automatically get filled in.  Is this scenario possible and where can I learn how to do this?

### Echo (Contact Info which would be one list)

```
Name     Client        Address      URL         Email
John Doe Alpha Client  1234 Blvd rd www.url.com john.doe@url.com
```

### Bravo (order in process which would be another list)

```
Name     Client        Item      Quantity Shipping Order Processed
John Doe Alpha Client  Gold Leaf 10       Yes      Yes
```

Info would be pulled from List `Echo` and will automatically fill List `Bravo` when you enter `Alpha Client` in `Bravo` it will fill `Bravo`'s name with `John Doe`.  I would like an end result to occur when the drop down of `Bravo`'s `Order Processed` is selected to `yes` it will move everything to a new List of completed transactions and removing everything from the List `Bravo`.

I have found where I can create a List, `Right Click > Add Column > Select Lookup` but it wont auto fill from one column selection.  Does the Lookup have to be first in the List?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on your requirement. I hope its not very tough task.

Comment: I will try with an edit.

Comment: Calling your lists "Echo" and "Bravo" made this question really hard to follow. If you call them "Orders" and "Clients" it'd be much easier to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

You've got about three different questions going on here, but here goes:

1. It sounds like when you select a client on your orders form, you would like to see additional data from the client populating onto the form. To do this you'll need to query the clients list whenever a new client is selected.  You can use CSOM or REST along with jQuery to do this, and you'd need to bind the query to the DOM event that fires when you select a client.
2. The "Add Column" feature in lookups will not work inside the new/edit form, it will only pertain to saved data.
3. This is just my opinion, but creating a new list for completed transactions and moving content between lists on status change is a bad idea, and will lead to added complexity (and headaches for you) down the road. Better to just leave the orders as they are with Status=Completed as your filter. But if you have a compelling justification to do the separate list, you'll have to write an Event Receiver in .NET code running in a Farm Solution. (MS says you can write an "app" to get this functionality but I suspect that's easier said than done).

   Oh, and technically it's possible to write an event receiver in a sandbox solution, but please take my advice and don't do that. Code running in sandbox is, let's say, unreliable.

Comment: thanks for your input.  I will take your advise and create a `processing` view and `completed` view for the orders.  Would their be any issues with exporting the list if I am pulling the clients info from another list?

Comment: Exporting lists with lookups is touchy.  I would ask a separate question for that.